# Переделать код под jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не работает нижеприведенный код на jQuery. Помогите его переделать под jQuery

```
function hide_div() {
   //var rnd_200 = Math.round(Math.random()*4) + 7; swap_img('loader_' + rnd_200);
   clearTimeout(show_delay); show_delay = null;
   if ( ! obj_float_div ) return;
   obj_float_div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   obj_float_div.style.left = "-3000px";
   obj_float_div = false;
}

var IE = (document.all);
var NC = (document.layers);
var Opera = (document.getElementById);
function  getWidth()
{
    if (IE) return document.body.clientWidth;
    if (NC) return window.innerWidth;
    if (Opera) return document.body.offsetWidth;
    return 1024;
}

var cmw;
var hfw;
var ww;

function recount()
{
    var ttt;
    if (window.getSize().x>=1690)
    {
        ttt=8;
    }
    else if (window.getSize().x>=1260)
    {
        ttt=6;
    }
    else
    {
        ttt=4;
    }
    cmw=ttt*205;
    hfw=cmw-5;
    ww=hfw+30;
}


window.onload=resizecontent;
window.onresize=resizecontent;

function resizecontent() 
{
    recount();
    if ($('header').style) $('header').style.width=hfw+'px';
    $('footer').style.width=hfw+'px';
    if (document.getElementById('contentmain'))
    {
        $('contentmain').style.width=cmw+'px';
    }
    else
    {
        $('wrapper').style.width=ww+'px';
    }
    if ($('imagezoom_overlay'))
    {
        $('imagezoom_overlay').style.width = document.body.offsetWidth + "px";
        $('imagezoom_overlay').style.height = window.getScrollSize().y + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: А как правильно это сделать? Не могли бы написать?
А то я совсем не шарю.
Спасибо.

Comment: А вообще бразуер показывает эту ошибку:

Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'window.getSize' is not a function
Error thrown at line 32, column 1 in recount() in http://www.site.ru/test/size2.js:
    if (window.getSize().x>=1690)
called from line 55, column 1 in resizecontent() in http://www.site.ru/test/size2.js:
    recount();

Comment: Вы можете написать какой Вам нужен результат?

Comment: В общем это функция ресайза страницы. При определенном разрешении экрана, она ресайзиться.

Comment: Есть движок сайта на livestreet. Есть шаблон на MooTools. Этот код там работает отлично!

Есть такой же шаблон только на jQuery. Этот код там не работает. Видимо конфликт какой-то, либо этот код не принимается jQuery и ошибку выдает. Вот.

Comment: `'window.getSize' is not a function` какбэ намекает нам, где суть проблемы. Нет такой функции, `getSize` (область имен, по умолчанию, как раз `window`).

А вообще код — ад, погибель и Индия. Его бы переписать, если по-уму...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('imagezoom_overlay').style` - по-моему это и есть ошибка, воспользуйтесь [jQuery.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) и [jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) и селектор id выглядит так: [`$('#yourId')`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

---

```
function resizecontent() 
{
    recount();
    $('#header').width(hfw);
    $('#footer').width(hfw);
    if ($('#contentmain').length>0)
    {
        $('#contentmain').width(cmw);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#wrapper').width(ww);
    }
    if ($('#imagezoom_overlay').length>0)
    {
        $('#imagezoom_overlay').width(document.body.offsetWidth);
        $('#imagezoom_overlay').height(window.getScrollSize().y);
    }
}
```

если в дальнейшем будут ошибки, постарайтесь самостоятельно воспользоваться документацией, она очень подробная

Comment:     function $(obj) {
      return document.getElementById(obj);
    }

Comment: uWeb. Спасибо за ответ. Но куда его вставлять? Я вообще не бум-бум. 

Spectre. Код не работает...

Comment: я исправил jQuery-часть кода, надеясь что ``header, footer, contentmain, wrapper и imagezoom_overlay`` - это id-шники, но вы сами написали, что ошибки есть и в других местах

Comment: Будь добры, пожалуйста, исправьте и другие ошибки...
Я просто блин уже изучаю, замучался все туда сюда менять...

Comment: Есть движок сайта на livestreet. Есть шаблон на MooTools. Этот код там работает отлично!

Есть такой же шаблон только на jQuery. Этот код там не работает. Видимо конфликт какой-то, либо этот код не принимается jQuery и ошибку выдает. Вот.

Comment: Попробовал так передалать:

function recount()
{
 var ttt;
 if ($(window.getSize().x>=1690)
 {
   alert("ttt=8");
size2.js:32 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
 }
 else if ($(window.getSize().x>=1260)
 {
  alert("ttt=6");
 }
 else
 {
  alert("ttt=4");
 }
 cmw=ttt*205;
 hfw=cmw-5;
 ww=hfw+30;
}


Ошибка. Полагаю проблема в alert("ttt=8"); и т.д. Что поменять?

Answer (score 2):

Вижу кучу ошибок, потому что кто-то не курит маны.

1. Не `$('someid')`, а `$('#someid')`.
2. Не `$('#someid').style.width = x+'px';`, а `$('#someid')[0].style.width = x+'px';` , `$('#someid').css({'width': x+'px'});` или `$('#someid').width(x);` .
3. В функции hideDiv() используются переменные, не представленные в листинге.
4. Определение браузеров кривое: зачем-то присутствует NC, Opera всегда определяется.
5. getScrollSize() вообще взята из mootools. Если правильно понимаю, это должно было быть `window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight` .

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
В общем переделал нижепредставденный код, но все равно не работает...
Что не так?

    var cmw;
    var hfw;
    var ww;
    
    function recount()
    {
        var ttt;
        if (window.getSize().x>=1690)
        {
            ttt=8;
        }
        else if (window.getSize().x>=1260)
        {
            ttt=6;
        }
        else
        {
            ttt=4;
        }
        cmw=ttt*205;
        hfw=cmw-5;
        ww=hfw+30;
    }

Comment: window.onload=resizecontent;

    window.onresize=resizecontent;

Comment: function resizecontent() 

    {

        recount();

        $('#header').css({'width': hfw+'px'});

        $('#footer').css({'width': hfw+'px'});

        if ($('#contentmain').length>0)

        {

            $('#contentmain').css({'width': cmv+'px'});

        }

        else

        {

            $('#wrapper').css({'width': ww});

        }

        if ($('#imagezoom_overlay').length>0)

         {

            $('#imagezoom_overlay').width(document.body.clientWidth);

            $('#imagezoom_overlay').height(window.innerHeight().y);

        }

    }

Comment: > Что не так?

Все, что связано с этим: [http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow][1].

[1]:http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow